# How does hypotenuse approaches $\Delta{x}$ and angle $\phi$ approaches x as $\Delta$ becomes smaller in this picture

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I am watching a video on derivatives
[image]

It says, "Now what happens if $\Delta{x}$ gets smaller and smaller, the hypotenuse of the orange triangle almost coincides with the arch of the circle and approaches $\Delta{x}$ and the angle $\phi$ approaches x".

I don't understand how the hypotenuse approaches $\Delta{x}$ ( $\Delta{x}$ is an angle to my understanding) and angle $\phi$ approaches x as $\Delta$ becomes smaller. Please help me understand.